# RIGHT FRONT BURNER DOESNT STAY LIT

Tags: gas-burner

DELONGHI DEFSGG36SS GAS STOVE

THE right front burner does not ignite automatically when the knob is turned.

It will light with a lighter. However, it does not stay lit when the knob is released.

Comment: so, what's your question?

Comment: Probably dirty and needs fixing.  Seeing it is gas, I would get the professionals in.

Comment: Please don’t shout at us. Edit the question title.

Comment: The reason it won’t light is probably the same root cause as it going out sounds like the valve needs to be cleaned.

Answer (score 1):

From the pictures in the manual, it looks like there is a flame-out detector next to each burner.  If the burner lights OK, but won't stay lit, then the detector may have failed.

Answer (score 0):

Your gas valve is failing, depending on "type of gas" regulates the size orifice the gas comes out of.